# How to show that $e^{-ax^2}$ is an element of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as the space of all functions $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |x|^k |f^{(l)}(x)| <\infty,$$

for all $k,l\in \mathbb{N}$. That is to say that if we fix any $k,l\in \mathbb{N}$, there is $A_{k,l}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$|x|^k |f^{(l)}(x)|\leq A_{k,l}.$$

Now, it is usually said that $e^{-ax^2}$ is an element of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. But how can we prove this?

I've been thinking about this for a while and I have no idea on what has to be done. The function $e^{-ax^2}$ is bounded by $1$, but that is certainly not enough, since it covers just the case $k = 0$, $l = 1$.

How does one prove that $e^{-ax^2}$ is an element of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Did you notice that $f^{(l)}$ is always a polynomial times $e^{-ax^2}?$ That means that all you need to check is that $p(x)e^{-ax^2}$ is bounded on the line.

Comment: Indeed it is quite easy to show that $f^{(l)}(x) = P_{l}(x)e^{-ax^2}$ for some polynomial $P_l(x)$. Now, I've been thinking on how to show that this is bounded but I had no idea up to know. Indeed looking at the graphs I'm quite convinced of this fact, but I've had no idea yet. I believe this has to do with the Taylor series expansion of $e^{-ax^2}$ but I still didn't get it. What is the idea on showing that $P_l(x)e^{-ax^2}$ is bounded?

Comment: If $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n,$ then $|p(x)| \le C|x|^n$ for large $|x|.$

Comment: I got the idea. I first proved that if $f$ is continuous with finite limits $\pm \infty$ then $f$ is bounded. It thus suffices to show that $|x|^n / e^{ax^2}$ has finite limits at $\pm \infty$. For that I used that $e^{ax^2} \geq 1 + \cdots + (ax^2)^{n+1}/(n+1)!$ and the squeeze theorem applied to $0 \leq |x|^n / e^{ax^2} \leq |x|^n / (1 + \cdots + (ax^2)^{n+1}/(n+1)!)$, which gives $|x|^n/e^{ax^2}\to 0$ when $x\to \pm \infty$. Together with $|p(x)|\leq C|x|^n$ and the fact that $|p(x)|e^{-ax^2}$ is continuous the result follows. Is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you need to show that any derivative of $e^{-ax^{2}}$ is of type $e^{-ax^{2}}P(x)$ for some polynomial $P$, now observe that $e^{-ax^{2}}$ decreases faster than any polynomial, you may use L'Hopital to deduce this fact.